# Why is there oxidation in the anode?

Tags: electrochemistry

In a battery, I don't understand what makes the element in the anode separate from the anode to become a positive charge in the electrolyte and leave some electrons inside the anode.

Also, why does the molecule separated from the anode leave electrons on the anode?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘separate from the anode’?

Comment: So you’re basically asking why they react? The diffusion is because one can dissolve the other can’t. There would be no diffusion if there was no reaction.

Comment: For example in a zinc-copper battery, zinc^2+ ions separate from the zinc electrode and go in the solution. This leaves a negative charge in the zinc electrode which gives it a potential

Comment: Again, the ions don’t ‘separate’. The metal reacts giving away electrons to become an ion which is then free to dissolve and diffuse.

Answer (score 1):

We define anode to be the electrode where oxidation takes place.

Oxidation signifies loss of electrons and Reduction signifies gain of electrons.

For example, in this electrochemical cell,

[image]

Copper has more reduction potential than Zinc. So it will be easy for copper to reduce (or gain electrons) and if copper is reducing (or gaining electrons) then there must a source of these electrons. These electrons are supplied by Zinc (which gets oxidized).

At anode, $Zinc(s)$ in losing electrons and converting into $Zn^{+2}(aq)$ ions and at cathode, $Cu^{+2}(aq)$ ions are gaining these electrons lost by $Zinc(s)$ and converting into $Cu(s)$.

These reactions occur because they are spontaneous $(\Delta G =-ve)$. Spontaeous reactions occur in nature by themselves without any external driving force. A system aims for least energy $(\Delta H = -ve)$ and maximum entropy $(\Delta S = +ve)$ and its the combination of both these factors that result in spontaneous processes. $(\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S)$.

Answer (score 0):

The driving force is the transfer of electrons from one substance to another. This is favored by thermodynamics. In a galvanic cell or battery, the completion of the circuit provides a path for the substance at the anode (oxidation) to give electrons through the circuit to the substance at the cathode (reduction).